Can finite element exterior calculus be used for the proof of discrete stability?
I've heard about Finite Element Exterior Calculus (FEEC) and its applications in numerical simulations, but can FEEC be utilised to prove discrete stability in computational methods? If so, can the discrete stability analysis be made on curved meshes?
Any insights or resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated, especially for someone new to FEEC. Thank you!
